# Style with Leaflet and Mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm new to leaflet.js and mapbox and I'm trying to work out how to add a custom style to a map. It should be straightforward only I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This works but I can't seem to add a custom style to it.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid')
.setView(latLong, 13)
```

This works with mapbox style 11, only it seem to be in a container format

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container id
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to login to your mapbox account and go to mapbox studio, there click on new style, then customize.
After you're done click on the share button top right and you'll get a style url looking something like this:

`mapbox://styles/<username>/oxpbfqo2peepoo3phxl7010cm` paste this into your code.

for styling leaflet maps you are limited to choose styles from one these providers: [here](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)

Answer (score 0):

I worked out where I was going wrong! I needed to added a style layer.

To my future self, for reference:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.mytokenstring';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map').setView([51.483728, 0.00], 15);

L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/[username]/[mystyleid').addTo(map);
```